# object does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

Tags: python, pandas, types, python-datetime

convert to datatype (in csv file)
(yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss(current column datatype) --(convert)--> 143141231(nanosec))

problem
-> object does not match format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

csv file 
ex)
      time
2019-01-01 0:00:00
2019-01-01 8:50:00
2019-01-01 8:50:00
2019-01-01 8:51:00
2019-01-01 8:51:00
2019-01-01 8:51:00

code

```
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data/test.csv")

df.head()

mydate =str(df["time"])

timestamp = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())

df["time"] = [str(df[timestamp()][t]) for t in range(len(df))]

df.head()

ns_precision = df
ns_precision.to_csv("data/test_convert.csv", index=False)
```

expect

     time
1131314141
1412313131
1312414123
1231225244
2421412141

---

result

```
ValueError: time data '0        
2019-01-01 0:00:00\n1 ... 2019-01-30 20:15:00\n
Name: time, Length: 77876, 
dtype: object' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: `str(df["time"])` this is where you are going wrong, you turned the whole column into one SINGLE string. also `timestamp()` is wrong, timestamp is not a function, its a float

Comment: thanks. i fixed timestamp -> pd.to_datetime()